# Smart encoding of 2 dimensional sensor data

Tags: encoding, compression

I have a 2D position sensor which returns the pressed locations on it. For example, a sensor that 8x8 sized returns 64 points. It can give up to 1000 frames per second. All data must be send to GUI without lost. One frame consists of 64bytes and 64000bytes must be send in one second. Unfortunately, the communication speed with GUI is not enough for this.

Due to consecutive frames are very similar, i want to send more intelligently. This frames can be likened image/video frames.

How can I turn this similarity into advantage? I have a FPGA that is cyclone2 scale from Altera. Some people knows that this FPGA is not suitable for implementing complex math algorithms.

I need low cost,easy implementable, maybe not most effective but moderate algorithms that can be runs on mid-scale processor. Improvement %30 is acceptable for this work.

Which algorithms/methods are recommended for this work?

Note: Sensor which i use is an analog one, not a 0-1 manner sensor

The question can be changed as follows: What are the low-cost, easy implementable algorithms when encoding similar frames? Without thinking data sizes, please.

Comment: your edit makes little sense: What you'd do for encoding depends on the data you're encoding, and what you need to achieve.

Comment: You said you have 1000 values per second, right, and a single sensor? How do you digitize that sensor? What kind of physical excitation is your sensor subject to, and what's the maximum frequency of that? what is the probability distribution of the sensor value? There's no "universal best and easiest" method, you really need to be way more specific, especially the way you describe this, none of the numbers in your post agree with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Many options here, but more details are needed about the differences.

You say you need to send 64000 bytes so I assume 1 byte per sample (so values 0-255)

What you can do, is innstead of sending 1000 full frames, create a separate array of booleans for each frame: thus 8x8 = 64 bits. If the bit is 1, the frame has changed, otherwise not. Than you have to send the changes only (for when the bit is 1):

- Advantage: on average less data need to be send
- In worst case, slightly more data is sent (64 bits).

Comment: um, I'm a digital comms engineer, and thus I'm a big fan of source coding (i.e. compression), but at 64 kB/s, none of this is even remotely necessary.

Comment: @MarcusMüller True, but if the average load 'needs' to be reduced this is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is bad: No GUI can update 1000 times a second, a human user can't see changes at 1000 frames per second, so there's literally no reason why you need to send 1000 frames per second to a GUI.

This sounds like you really should reconsider your system and software approach.

Preprocess the data in a separate thread, and only update your GUI maybe 25 times a second.

64kB per second is essentially **nothing** on a modern computer or even microcontroller (we can easily process 100 million complex-valued samples per second on modern CPUs), so my guess is that you simply wrote an extremely inefficient program.

Nothing requires you to use an FPGA: That's

1. overkill for the amount of data and
2. way harder than I think you assume it is to use, and
3. it doesn't solve the underlying issue of wrong system design.

So, using an FPGA will only make your life harder.

Comment: I have a ready to use hardware and i can't changed it. This is the work what asked for me. I didn't say anything about a real time or 1000 frame update rate requirement. GUI works in postprocess manner. First dump the data, then shows x64,x128 slows of it. I only say about how can i encoding effectively :)

Comment: A standart baud rate 115200 bits/s. It is equivalent about to 11kByte.(One character is 10bits).This is slower than 64kByte. I need a solution not for only this time, i will meet a 64x64 sized sensor next time. I want to plan accordingly and learn the methods.

Comment: You said in your question yourself, in verbatim "all data must be sent to GUI", and that's really not the case. It needs to be processed, ok, but again, this data rate is so low that an FPGA is not even remotely necessary. Any decent microcontroller can handle that, and to connect a microcontroller to something that displays a GUI, you'd typically not use a 115.2 kb/s serial line, but e.g. USB 2 Full speed at 12 Mb/s, again something that every decent microcontroller does these days.

Comment: No debate,OK,thanks.